# How to increase the upload file size when uploading file to google drive through your app?

Tags: ios, iphone, wpf, model-view-controller, google-drive-api

I have integrated google drive to my iOS , desktop(window) and web application using google drive api . when i upload pics or video less than 4Mb , it uploads to my default drive folder, but when i try to upload more than that it gives me exception. what is the best solution for that?

Comment: What type of uploadType are you using here? what is the file size? please post your question clearly including the exception you are getting with Drive API.

Comment: i am uploading mp4 movie , size less then 4mb sent to drive but not more than that.... error in status. is there any upload limit size? we have to increase?